# Query works from pgAdmin. Won't work from PHP with no errors

Tags: php, postgresql, phppgadmin

I'm rebuilding app for my client. I write scripts to migrate data from old db to new one. To prevent empty values in column `etiquette_start` (what happened in old db), I run

```
UPDATE items 
SET etiquette_start = 'E' 
WHERE trim(both ' ' from etiquette_start) = '' 
OR etiquette_start is null;
```

just after importing data. The problem is that scripts works fine on pgAdmin III, but it won't execute on php script. PHP Syntax error isn't the issue here - putting other queries in variable holding query quoted above resulted in successfull data manipulation. There is no PHP error on the page and in logs.

Comment: Find a simpler SQL solution for your WHERE clause.

Comment: Problem could be solved easily if there were no '  ' like strings in db instead of just empty values or nulls. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the database log say? Set `log_statement=all` and try again. What does the database actually get?

Comment: what does your php code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE items 
SET etiquette_start = 'E' 
WHERE length(trim(both ' ' from etiquette_start)) = 0 
OR etiquette_start is null;
```

Comment: The expression `length(trim(both ' ' from etiquette_start)) = 0` does *exactly* the same as `trim(both ' ' from etiquette_start) = ''`, which in turn is *exactly* the same as `trim(etiquette_start) = ''`. There is no reason to do it like this *at all*.

Comment: @Erwin You are perfectly right but you probably did not carefully read the question. The author had problem with PHP, not Postgres.

Comment: How would the presented alternative help with PHP? The OP has an unrelated problem, that's not covered properly in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - It should be quite clear from the question that the author does not know how to properly write down empty string constant as a parameter to his sql query in PHP. As we do not see the code I suggested sql query in which he does not have to use empty string.

Comment: That's not clear *at all* from the question, especially as there are more single quotes in the statement.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - In this case I cannot help you, sorry.

Comment: I wasn't asking for help. I want to make clear that nobody should use this inefficient query. No offense.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, you can simplify the `trim()` call and prevent empty updates:

```
UPDATE items 
SET    etiquette_start = 'E'
WHERE (trim(etiquette_start) = '' OR etiquette_start IS NULL) -- parens needed
AND    etiquette_start IS DISTINCT FROM 'E';
```

Since space (`' '`) is the default character to be removed by [**`trim()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html), these expressions are 100% equivalent:

```
trim(etiquette_start)

trim(both ' ' from etiquette_start
```